# Shell script running on boot can't run mysql

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I have a shell that executes on boot via `init.d`, to run a python script upon boot:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          start.sh
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Prepare device
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

sudo /usr/bin/python /dir/script.py &

exit
```

Part of the scripts pulls data from a database:

```
cmd = "mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -upi -pXXXX -e 'some SQL code"
Messages = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )
```

The python script correctly initializes on boot and runs end-to-end when executed from the console. However, when executed during the boot process, it looks like mysql service isn't fully functional yet:
`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111 "Connection refused")`

How can I make sure the shell doesn't run until the mysql service is up?

Comment: Real process supervision systems (which SysV-style init scripts are not) allow you to specify dependencies, preconditions, postconditions, etc. Would you be open to using such a tool?

Comment: Even if you use [Runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) -- which doesn't actually have dependency management as such, but is built to be tiny and easily fit on embedded systems such as a Pi -- you can write your software to fail fast if its dependencies aren't up, and tell the supervision system to rerun it until it succeeds.

Comment: ...beyond that, though, using a subprocess to run the `mysql` tool from Python is... suboptimal. If you were using a Python-native MySQL library, you could catch exceptions you care about and handle them appropriately -- even if that means waiting and trying again later.

Comment: (Though really, running MySQL on a Raspberry Pi is suboptimal altogether -- if you were using SQLite instead, you wouldn't need an extra daemon at all, so there wouldn't be any kind of startup-process ordering to worry about in the first place).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good suggestion. I use MySQLdb in the python script to handle error in the `while True:` loop. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is running on a Raspberry Pi, I assume you're using `systemd`.  You need the correct dependencies to tell `systemd` that your script needs MySQL to be running.

From https://serverfault.com/questions/482730/systemd-dependencies-and-boot-order#725684

> `After=dirsrv.target` - Will ensure the smb.service is started after dirsrv.target.

In this case, you probably want something like 'After=mysqld.target`or whatever Raspbian's`systemd` calls MySQL this week.

---

If you're using SysV init, which it appears you are, even though that is uncommon on a Raspberry Pi, make sure your init script launches after MySQL does.  For example, if MySQL is launched from `/etc/init.d/rc2.d/S45mysql` or `/etc/rc2.d/S45mysql`, place or symlink your script in the same directory/directories as `S45mysql`, with the name `S46query_mysql`.  By starting with `S46`, it will run after all of the scripts whose names start with `S45` have finished.

If you have other dependencies, number your script after the last of them.  That is, if you depend upon, as in my example, `S45mysql`, but also `S55httpd` and `S86tomcat` (all of these being made-up examples), your script's name or symlink should start with `S87` or higher.

Comment: There's more than one distro available for the Pi. Insofar as what the OP is providing is clearly a SysV-style script, you should probably keep the content from your original rendition of this answer around, even if adding systemd-specific content as well.